# Why the following C language code gives this output?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    char p[20];
    char *s="string";
    int i;
    int length= strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        p[i]=s[length-i];  // it shows expected values when checked here, character by character.

    //But, if it's printed as string, it shows blank.
    printf("%s",p);

    //And now, again checking it character by character, it behaves like nothing is stored.
    for(i=0;i<strlen(p);i++)
        printf("%c",p[i]);
    }
}
```

It prints nothing. When traversing the `for` loop and checking variable `p`'s value, it shows expected values; but it doesn't hold anything when checked outside the for loop.
And then 
Why?

Comment: `void main()` is implementation-defined in C and is illegal in global namespace in standard C++. You should use standard `int main(void)` unless you have some special reason to use special form of `main`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: `void main()` is not a valid signature in C, not just _implementation defined_. The standard is quite clear about this. And there is not just `int main(void)`, but also `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: @Olaf No, he is correct, `void main()` can be perfectly fine in some implementations, most notably all freestanding implementations. The standard is certainly not clear at all, it is quite vague. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518). I have some references to the C99 rationale etc to show why the standard is vague.

Comment: @Lundin: I know very well, but I strongly doubt this is a _freestanding environment_. But agreed, I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: @Olaf The C standard is not even clear about which forms that can exist on a hosted system. Check the link I posted. The C99 rationale contradicts sections in the standard. This part of the standard is simply very poorly written.

Comment: @Lundin: Agreed. But OS/Environment may add additional restrictions, e.g. POSIX. Typically, they allow additional parameters, and the `void` form (never saw `int main(int argc)` actually using `argc`, becauseit makes little sense without `argv`, too. I tend to accept omitting arguments from the right, but not different arguments. But a return value of `void` is not acceptable in any variant IMO.

Comment: @Lundin: Another hint the standard does not mean "all is allowed" is that it explicitly states it for freestanding environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assignment `p[i]=s[length-i]` sets `p[0]` to the null-terminator that finishes the string `s`.

Hence attempting to use `printf` on the array `p` will not output anything.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are copying `s[length - 0]`, which copies the string terminator character `\0` at the beggining of your new string. So when it is going to be printed, it will stop at the first character.

EDIT:

And, as Sourav Ghosh pointed out, the second `strlen()` will return 0

Comment: ...and the next `strlen()` will return 0.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn't even notice that one

Comment: Please [edit] and add. . (sorry, gotta run to get the bus back home)

Answer (score 1):

`s[length-i]` will be `'\0'`, which is at the end of string, when `i = 0`.

Seeing it, `printf("%s",p);` will print zero-character string and `strlen(p)` will return zero, so the body of second loop will be executed zero times.